# Apache Ambari 2.2.2.0 install ZooKeeper throw incorrrect stack version

Tags: centos, apache-zookeeper, ambari

When i am installing ZooKeeper using Apache Ambari,CentOS 7.2,Apache Ambari version 2.2.2.0。It comes out:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZOOKEEPER/3.4.5.2.0/package/scripts/zookeeper_server.py", line 179, in <module>
    ZookeeperServer().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 219, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZOOKEEPER/3.4.5.2.0/package/scripts/zookeeper_server.py", line 70, in install
    self.configure(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZOOKEEPER/3.4.5.2.0/package/scripts/zookeeper_server.py", line 49, in configure
    zookeeper(type='server', upgrade_type=upgrade_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons/os_family_impl.py", line 89, in thunk
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZOOKEEPER/3.4.5.2.0/package/scripts/zookeeper.py", line 40, in zookeeper
    conf_select.select(params.stack_name, "zookeeper", params.current_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/conf_select.py", line 266, in select
    shell.checked_call(get_cmd("set-conf-dir", package, version), logoutput=False, quiet=False, sudo=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'conf-select set-conf-dir --package zookeeper --stack-version 2.4.3.0-227 --conf-version 0' returned 1. 2.4.3.0-227 Incorrect stack version
```

When I am executed the command in terminal:

```
conf-select set-conf-dir --package zookeeper --stack-version 2.4.3.0-227 --conf-version 0
```

it return:

```
Incorrect stack version
```

How to make it right? Where is going wrong？

Answer (score 0):

**Message meaning:**

> Incorrect stack version

Means that no such stack present at `/usr/hdp/x.x.x.x-xxxx` location.

**What to do:**

You need to check if you have installed packages on nodes(check stack folder presence). If not, you can go to host management tab on Ambari and reinstall packages.